# Insertion with two or more tables from Wso2 ESB with DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have one query:-

In my ESB 4.7.0, Dss is 3.0.1

I wish to insert the data reliably into database,for that i am getting one array list from client.
That array i need to insert into 3 different tables.Each table gave to me returned generated key.which will help to insert into
2nd table,same process for 3rd table.
for this i am using 3 different insertion operations in wso2esb using wso2dss,the insertion is happening  nicely ..

@my issue is while i am inserting into 2nd or 3rd table the error has been occurred due to network issue or any data related issue.
In that case my transaction could be roll back.i have done in transaction mediator but it's helpful for within the sequence .
it's not reflecting to any other sequence , so how could i do this.for this may i use any class mediator or any new thing.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction mediator is designed to cater the atomicity requirement. Since you are using insertion only without the involvement of deletion you can pass the primary key of inserted entry in the first table to a class mediator and delete but i think, in this case atomicity will not be guranteed. Therefore the concept of transaction is not achieved in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using three different opperations you can use DSS boxcarring feature along with Query Request Export feature  which enables you to do transactions in a coordinated way. Please refer [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS300/Boxcarring) to see how you can use boxcarring feature.  It allows individual queries executed in a boxcarring session to communicate with each other. The concept is 'exporting' a specific result element so that the next calling query will get that result element as a query parameter. So, if you've two queries, namely, 'query1' and 'query2' that's executed sequentially in a boxcarring session, and if 'query1' has a specific result element and that element is exported with the name 'foo', then 'query2' also gets a query param named 'foo'. So when this boxcarring session is executed, the query1's exported value will be passed into query2 as an input parameter.

Comment: But how to specify this ID to next query when not knowing it?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement the ideal solution is to use Boxcarring. Boxcarring is a method of grouping a set of service calls together and executing them at once. Where applicable, a boxcarring session works in a transactional manner such as when used with an RDBMS data source.
The 'Data Service Hosting' feature facilitates boxcarring by grouping service calls in the server side. As a result, special service clients are not required and as usual, successive service calls can be made to the server to participate in a boxcarring session.

For boxcarring to function, a transport that supports session management, such as HTTP, must be used. The service client should also support session management by returning back session cookies when sent by the server. Axis2 Service Clients have full support for session management.

Please find the [WSO2 original documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS300/Boxcarring) on boxcarring and [this useful blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-create-simple-proxy-service-with.html) that explain how to work with boxcarring step by step.